# Best way to hold on to a shared_ptr returned from a factory Create method

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, factory

I have a scoped guard object factory that returns a `shared_ptr` to a guard that I want to hold on to for the duration of my scope.

The factory Create method declaration is:

```
virtual boost::shared_ptr<GenericGuard> Create() const = 0;
```

My question is - is it better to write:

```
boost::shared_ptr<SelectorGenericGuard> guard = factory->Create();
```

or:

```
const boost::shared_ptr<SelectorGenericGuard>& guard = factory->Create();
```

The first version can/may/will create a copy of the `shared_ptr` and so can/may/will cause additional reference counter incrementations - the second is clearly less readable and I can't make my mind as to what my "default" should be - all things considered readability is usually my favorite and I'd like to hear what others think.

Or should I maybe just use `auto_ptr` (`unique_ptr` in the future) here and use the first more readable form for free? (the only downside here is using `auto_ptr` ;) )

Comment: No sane implementation will actually ever perform a copy during copy initialization. The two will be equivalent in performance. The latter, of course, will prevent you from modifying the value, in particular, you won't be able to reset the pointer to dismiss the guard early.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite likely both would result in exactly the same code:

1. This binds the return value to a constant reference.
   Theoretical overhead without optimization: One reference more memory, additional indirection on access.
   Practically: **Overhead optimized away** under the as-if rule.

   ```
   const boost::shared_ptr<SelectorGenericGuard>& guard = factory->Create();
   ```
2. This saves the return value by initializing a variable.
   Theoretical overhead without optimization: One move and one dtor
   Practically: **Overhead optimized away** under the copy-ellision rule (exception to as-if rule).
   Added danger: Optimization only possible if the types match exactly.

   ```
   boost::shared_ptr<SelectorGenericGuard> guard = factory->Create();
   ```
3. Same as 2, but no possibility of type-mismatch and shorter (my preferred option):

   ```
   auto guard = factory->Create();
   ```

Regarding `auto_ptr`:
Always prefer `unique_ptr`.
Be aware of the pitfalls if you cannot: Move semantics where copy is written, thus failure of standard algorithms and containers. Consider defining your own not copyable version, and do explicit moves everywhere needed. Keep it out of the ABI though, for later replacement: Function arguments (and exception types).

Regarding `unique_ptr`: If you can do so, a `unique_ptr` is preferable to `shared_ptr` due to reduced (speak: no) overhead.

Comment: Thanks - I wish I could use auto... :)

Comment: do you have `decltype`? Or too old compiler?

Comment: Too old compiler and it's likely to stay this way for a while.

Comment: As to your edit - it seems you agree that a shared_ptr is a better choice for now then auto_ptr right?

Comment: No, prefer `auto_ptr` to `shared_ptr` due to overhead. Or maybe use a custom scoped_ptr which is `unique_ptr` without move semantics, and swap that out whenever you can (be sure you will be able to replace it whenever without breaking binary compatibility). Thus, never use your homebrew thing as exception type or function argument, and make sure it has the same layout as `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Even if the overhead is zero? (ie. not significant in terms of performance of the application - and considering your "avoid it like the plague" comment :) )

Comment: A tiny bit of hyperbole is good for you. It's just that `auto_ptr` is bad for standard algorithms and containers, due to moveing where copy was indicated.

Comment: Yes, that's why given the shared_ptr "only" problem is the inherent additional cost I tend to considered it the lesser of two evils unless the cost would be "significant" given a particular scenario - all in all thanks for your answer and comments - it helped me double check this and drop the additional clutter from my code :)